# Expanding and diminishing a list of sets

Tags: python, loops, set, slice

OK this is a tricky one to explain. It's the difficulty I have explaining it that makes it difficult to create the loop I want.

Consider this list of 10 sets

```
my_list_of_sets = [ 
{0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9},
{0,1,2,4,5,6,7}, 
{0,1,2,3,4,8,9},
{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 
{1,2,3,4,5,6}, 
{3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, 
{1,2,3,5,6,8,9},
{2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, 
{2,5,6,7,8,9}, 
{3,4,6,7,8,9}]
```

And I want to apply the following type of rules to expand the intersection products of these lists.

Rule1: my_list_of_sets[0] can intersect with my_list_of_sets with index 0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9.

Rule2: my_list_of_sets[1] can intersect with my_list_of_sets with index 0,1,2,4,5,6,7

RuleX:my_list_of_sets[x] can intersect with my_list_of_sets with indexes in my_list_of_sets[x]

RuleN: My_list_of_sets[1] cannot coexist with my_list_of_sets[3] or my_list_of_sets[8] or my_list_of_sets[9].

And to do this in recursion until I expand an output list of sets that can "coexist".

Loop flow I perform

```
my_output_list_item = my_list_of_sets[0] & my_list_of_sets[0]
```

> {0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9}

```
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[1] #Skipped no index
```

> {1,2,4,5,7}

Then I can continue along to intersect with indexes 2,4,5,7...

```
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[2]
```

> {0,1,2,4}

```
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[4]
```

> {1,2,4}

until I've gone along my_list_of_sets[0] as indexes into my_list_of_sets and found a set that has no 'objections' {1,2,4}. Sorry for that word I can't think of a better one for the sets that can intersect.

Issue 1 
You will notice that if the first iteration of my loop is arbitrarily my_list_of_sets[0] & my_list_of_sets[1] index 3 is dropped in the first iteration. I would get a different outcome than if the first pass is is arbitrarily my_list_of_sets[0] & my_list_of_sets[2].

```
my_output_list_item = my_list_of_sets[0] & my_list_of_sets[2] #Skipped one index
```

> {0,1,2,3,4,9}

```
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[3]
```

> {1,3,4,9}

```
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[4]
```

> {1,3,4}

```
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[1]
```

> {1,4}

I got {1,2,4} and {1,4} based on the index where I started the intersections. 
This means my input data order has become relevant to the outcome and it's a set, which has no inherent order.

For this reason I attempted to solve issue 1 by using a rolling slice window to go along the set and perform the intersection from all starting indices.
Here's the code I have so far which does that.

```
my_output_list = set()
for i in range(len(my_list_of_sets)):
    set_as_list = list(my_list_of_sets[i])  #need a list here because it will be indexed from various offsets
    for slice_index in range(0, len(set_as_list)):  # the index is used to make sure all items are started with every other bd
        new_item = my_list_of_sets[i]
        for bd in set_as_list[slice_index::] + set_as_list[:slice_index:]:
            if bd in new_item:  # need this if statement as new_item is getting smaller each loop of bd.
                new_item = new_item.intersection(my_list_of_sets[bd])
        my_output_list.add(frozenset(new_item))
```

This enumerates to a my_output_list of 15 sets.

Issue 2: 
However this code still misses some combinations

```
my_output_list_item = my_list_of_sets[0] 
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[2] #Skipped one index
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[4] #Skipped one index
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[1]
```

`{1,2,4}`

```
my_output_list_item = my_list_of_sets[0] 
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[2] #Skipped one index
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[9] #Skipped two index
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[3]
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[4]
```

`{3,4}`

```
my_output_list_item = my_list_of_sets[0] 
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[2] #Skipped one index
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[0] #Skipped three index
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[1]
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[2]
my_output_list_item = my_output_list_item & my_list_of_sets[4]
```

`{1,2,4}`
and so on.

I believe this missing `{3,4}` is due to the rolling slice `bd` being sequentially increasing in index value and overlooking some possible combinations.

So whilst I already have the rolling slice `bd` for loop iteration 0 I think I additionally need an itertools to go across the index in all combinations of my_list_of_sets[0].

Couple of edits. I can't brute force all combos and remove the illegal ones.  It's len 100 list which is 100^100 combinations and the computer can't do it. 
I know my answer may lie in itertools, but I'm not imagining it for products of lists of >2 length.

Comment: Here's a stab at a more concise phrasing of your problem:

You're looking for the biggest group of sets that can all coexist (and to print out which sets are in that group). 

A group of sets can coexist if each set contains the indices of all other sets in the group.

Is that right?

Comment: Yes. The kicker is the recursive sequence in which you happen to assemble the sets <currently> effects the outcome.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your goal is. I think this captures most of your Rules: `all(all(my_list_of_sets[i] & u for i in u) for u in my_list_of_sets)`. But I don't understand what RuleN is about. FWIW, this looks like a [Block Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_design) problem.

Comment: Rule N is also achieved in the intersection but is the one that makes the code unstable depending on the sequence of the indices fed into the intersections.  You are indeed right about block design, the bd counter is a clue.  Let me study that wiki entry.

Comment: Interesting that your set 6 can't coexist with itself

Comment: Typo.  A set can exist with itself.  Will fix.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth a try from an AI [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) perspective. If you count up how many things a set excludes, and how many sets exclude that set, you can start from least-constrained and work up.

For your example above (right axis is how many things that set excludes, bottom axis is how many things exclude that set)

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0: 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 | 2
1: 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 | 3
2: 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 | 3
3: 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 | 2
4: 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 | 4
5: 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 | 3
6: 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 | 3
7: 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 | 3
8: 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 | 4
9: 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 | 4
   - - - - - - - - - - 
   7 4 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3
```

Constraint sums:

- 0 = 9
- 1 = 7
- 2 = 6
- 3 = 4
- 4 = 6
- 5 = 5
- 6 = 6
- 7 = 5
- 8 = 7
- 9 = 7

So, now that you've worked out your constraints:

1. Starting with your least-constrained set: 3
2. 3 wipes out 0, 2, 8
3. Add one of your next least-constrained still valid: 5
4. 5 wipes out 1, 9, 2
5. Add your next least-constrained still valid: 7
6. 7 wipes out 4 and 6
7. No more valid ones

You're left with a group of: 3, 5, 7

Comment: I can try this one in the morning. My worry is that I can get most satisfied combos quite quickly which is ideal for AI pattern match; but i also need to enumerate the weird ones, that might start from the most constrained then bounce to the middle constrained then see what's leftover.  I will code it tomorrow and report findings back.  One issue I also have is I don't know when i have the correct maximum number of combinations.

Comment: Yup! I think the classic approach would be to add a bit of randomization in (probability of picking not the next least constrained option) and run it a few times, then  take the best result. Running this multiple times should still be much faster than a brute force.

Comment: OK since this can get up to 12k combinations without even touching all corners it's become unmanageable, I won't review the output manually. I think I need to look for the orthogonal combinations, as I know they exist in the source data.